# how to do a vertical align in my case

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a vertical align for my texts. I also want to make sure the green background div need to cover from top to bottom inside the red color div. Currently the green color div only covers 90% of the red oolor div. I am not sure what happened in my case. Can anyone explain and help me out?

html

```
<div id='wrapper'>
   <div class='head'></div>
   <h2 class='title'>Warm-Up</h2>
</div>
```

css

```
.title{
    display: inline;   
    padding-left: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;    
    margin: 0;
}

.head{
    width: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #A9D075;
}

#wrapper{
    width:200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmS2f/3/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/rmS2f/6/

Your `html` structure will work but you need to change the styles:

```
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    line-height:50px;
}
.head {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #A9D075;
}
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```